# How do I include unordered list in jquery serialize array

Tags: jquery, list, serialization, html-lists

I'm using:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "processform.php",
  type: "post",
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function(d) {
    alert(d);
  }
});
```

to collect form input into an array.

Part of the form is an unordered list:

```
<ul class="sortable list" id="section_order">
    <li>Diet</li>
    <li>Complementary Treatments</li>
    <li>Herbal medicine and dietary supplements</li>
    <li>Self Help Practices</li>
    <li> Other Activities</li>
    </ul>
```

Which the serialize function is ignoring.

How do I include the order of the list items in the serialized array.

Thanks for you help

Comment: What are you asking? A list is not a form element

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize ???

Comment: OK my mistake, but I need to add a list to the name value pairs of the form elements I created using serialize ().